# mySql - search rows without reference in second table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

How do i search for all rows in the first table that has **no** reference in the second table.

The connection field is: res_srvs.id = inv_supp2srv.srvID

So, I want to get all table "res_srvs" rows that has no srvID in table "inv_supp2srv".

TABLE: res_srvs

```
Collation   Attributes
id  int(11)
clientID    int(6)
resNum  int(9)
net decimal(7,2)
tax decimal(7,2)
from_date(date)
```

TABLE: inv_supp2srv

```
Collation   Attributes
clientID    int(6)
invNum  int(10)
srvID   int(11)
amount  decimal(7,2)
valid   tinyint(1)
```

This is what i tried:

```
SELECT srv.net , srv.tax , srv.net+srv.tax AS amount, srv.id AS srv_id
FROM res_srvs AS srv , inv_supp2srv AS i2s 
WHERE srv.clientID = 1 
AND srv.from_date >= '2020-03-01' 
AND i2s.clientID = 1 
AND i2s.srvID = srv.id 
AND (NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM inv_supp2srv AS i2s
    WHERE i2s.srvID = srv.id
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` for second table and filter by `NULL` joined value like:

```
SELECT srv.net , srv.tax , srv.net+srv.tax AS amount, srv.id AS srv_id
FROM res_srvs AS srv 
LEFT JOIN inv_supp2srv AS i2s ON i2s.srvID = srv.id 
WHERE 
    srv.clientID = 1 
    AND srv.from_date >= '2020-03-01' 
    -- AND i2s.clientID = 1 not relevant condition
    AND i2s.srvID IS NULL;
```

Another approach is using `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT srv.net , srv.tax , srv.net+srv.tax AS amount, srv.id AS srv_id
FROM res_srvs AS srv 
WHERE 
    srv.clientID = 1 
    AND srv.from_date >= '2020-03-01' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT srvID FROM inv_supp2srv AS i2s WHERE i2s.srvID = srv.id 
    );
```

Comment: Hello again Slava. thank you, but the select i wrote here is part of a bigger one. so is it possible to write WHERE .... AND not exist in second table ?

Comment: @roi, sure you can. I added this approach to my answer. Both queries should to return same result, just you need to test which give better performance.

Comment: I think you missed `AND` before `NOT EXISTS`, no?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a left outer join with exclusion :

[image]

```
SELECT r.*
FROM res_srvs r
LEFT JOIN inv_supp2srv i
ON r.id = i.srvID
WHERE i.srvID IS NULL
AND (
-- Your others where clauses go there
);
```

Comment: Hi Cid. thank you very much, but the select i wrote here is part of a bigger one. so is it possible to write WHERE .... AND not exist in second table ?

Comment: Left Join will perform best, regardless of the query size. The above condition would work as long as srvID is the only column you want to check on.
If there are multiple columns you can add "AND" to the join query.

Comment: @roi you can, but I prefer using `JOIN`s, it makes the queries clearer and could be faster  to execute. To give an accurate answer, data sample, table structure with expected results would be welcome. (In a  [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) in example)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all table `res_srvs` rows that have no `srvID` in table `inv_supp2srv`.

It looks like you are overcomplicating this. I don't see the point for the `join` between the tables in the outer query - it attempts to match the tables, which contradicts the `not exists` condition.

I think you  just want:

```
select r.*
from res_srvs r
where  
    r.from_date >= '2020-03-01' 
    and r.clientID = 1
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from inv_supp2srv i
        where i.srvID = r.id and i.clientID = r.clientID
    )
```

I am unsure whether you want `clientID` in the correlation clause or not - your query makes it look like it is the case, so I added it.

Comment: Well, the query is much longer, so i need the join for other staff...

Comment: @roi: you want rows that do no exist in the other table, so I don't understand why you want to join it.